# Yahoo Finance ticker scraping using Library yfR

Tags: r, quantmod

Wondering if there is a way to use yf_get() to grab a previousClose value from Yahoo Finance if there is no value for the date given. For example:

```
curr <- yf_get(tickers, first_date = Sys.Date() - 1, last_date = Sys.Date())

prev_q <- yf_get(tickers = tickers, 
                         first_date = quarters[1]-.5,
                         last_date = quarters[1])

prev_q_closes <- round(prev_q$price_close,2)

prev_q2 <- yf_get(tickers = tickers, 
                 first_date = quarters[2]-.5,
                 last_date = quarters[2], thresh_bad_data = 0.45)

prev_q2_closes <- round(prev_q2$price_close,2)

prev_q3 <- yf_get(tickers = tickers, 
                 first_date = quarters[3]-.5,
                 last_date = quarters[3])

prev_q3_closes <- round(prev_q3$price_close,2)


close_prices <- cbind(prev_q3_closes, prev_q2_closes, prev_q_closes, current_close)

tick_close <- data.frame(Tickers = tickers,
                         ClosingPrices = close_prices,
                         PercentChanges = percent_changes)

dates <- rev(quarters)
dates_change <- as.character(format(dates, "%m-%d"))
#colnames(tick_close) <- c("Tickers", "Prev Q3 Closing Prices", "Prev Q2 Closing Prices", "Prev Q1 Closing Prices", "Current Closing Prices")
colnames(tick_close) <- c("Tickers", as.character(dates[1]), as.character(dates[2]), as.character(dates[3]), as.character(CurrentDate),
                          paste(dates_change[1],dates_change[2], sep=" to "), paste(dates_change[1], dates_change[3], sep=" to "),
                          paste(dates_change[1],as.character(format(CurrentDate, "%m-%d")), sep=" to "),  
                          paste(dates_change[3],as.character(format(CurrentDate, "%m-%d")), sep=" to "))
```

etc and I then grab the previous quarterly date values, for some Chinese companies on Yahoo Finance they do not have a value for December 31st, and my algorithm falls apart because it cannot grab a different value. I want it to grab the December 30th value IF there is no December 31st value on Yahoo Finance!

Comment: If `yfR` doesn't support that, then you could grab daily data, `arrange(date)`, `group_by(ticker)` and use tidyr's `fill` to fill NAs by carrying forward the previous non-NA value, then `filter` for the end of the quarter. `arrange` , `group_by` and `filter` are from the dplyr package.

Comment: which package would you use to do this? I need to get all available data from Yahoo Finance!

Comment: I use tidyquant, but also use tidyr’s fill to plug gaps where appropriate.